# arduino Ethernet ENC28J60

Tags: arduino, ethernet

Hi I am absolute newbee using ENC28J60, I want to upload some data to my seerver (in php) :

I take a php hosting from 0fees and now I can send the data to my server using : http://ashutest123.0fees.us/dataupload1.php?data=somedata and check the uploaded list of data in the table as http://ashutest123.0fees.us/showdata.php ——— u can take a view yourself.

I wrote an arduino code (using Aruino Uno and ENC28J60 module from ebay.in) using UIPEthernet lib

```cpp
#include <UIPEthernet.h> // Used for Ethernet

// **** ETHERNET SETTING ****
// Arduino Uno pins: 10 = CS, 11 = MOSI, 12 = MISO, 13 = SCK
// Ethernet MAC address - must be unique on your network - MAC Reads T4A001 in hex (unique in your network)
byte mac[] = { 0x54, 0x34, 0x41, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31 };                                      
// For the rest we use DHCP (IP address and such)

EthernetClient client;
char server[] = "ashutest123.0fees.us"; // IP Adres (or name) of server to dump data to
int  interval = 5000; // Wait between dumps

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);

  Serial.println("Tweaking4All.com - Temperature Drone - v2.0");
  Serial.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
  Serial.print("IP Address        : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.print("Subnet Mask       : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.subnetMask());
  Serial.print("Default Gateway IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.gatewayIP());
  Serial.print("DNS Server IP     : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.dnsServerIP());
}

void loop() {
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("-> Connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print( "GET /dataupload1.php?");
    client.print("data=");
    client.print( "somedata" );
    client.println( " HTTP/1.1");
    client.print( "Host: " );
    client.println(server)
    client.println( "Connection: close" );
    client.println();
    client.println();
    client.stop();
  }
  else {
    // you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("--> connection failed/n");
  }

  delay(interval);
}
```

when I run it in serial monitor it shows all ip, dns, gateway etc addresses as 0.0.0.0 ---- seems no dhcp abtained
then shows "connected"

no data goes to my server

Please help me I am in a need of it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this example code, it might help you alot to understand your problem and where it come from.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = {
  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02
};

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // this check is only needed on the Leonardo:
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for (;;)
      ;
  }
  // print your local IP address:
  printIPAddress();
}

void loop() {

  switch (Ethernet.maintain())
  {
    case 1:
      //renewed fail
      Serial.println("Error: renewed fail");
      break;

    case 2:
      //renewed success
      Serial.println("Renewed success");

      //print your local IP address:
      printIPAddress();
      break;

    case 3:
      //rebind fail
      Serial.println("Error: rebind fail");
      break;

    case 4:
      //rebind success
      Serial.println("Rebind success");

      //print your local IP address:
      printIPAddress();
      break;

    default:
      //nothing happened
      break;

  }
}

void printIPAddress()
{
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println();
}
```

Then I let you edit your code with your custom functions to get all informations you might need.

Note that if you set an hard-coded IP address even in a DHCP range it will be working.

V.